# Setting object key value and check for existence of the key

Tags: javascript

I wonder if there is a shorthand for this:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
 obj[key] = value;
}
```

The question comes from problem, that if you set not-existing key and it's value in js, there will be no warning or error. And it's really difficult afterthat to find that you've mistyped (for example) property name.

May be there is strict way of setting key-value to object?

Comment: I usually cover it with unit tests instead to ensure everything is working, javascript is such a brittle thing to use

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You could simply write a function or reduce it to one line like:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj[key] = value;
```

Or a function:

function assignProp(obj, key, value) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) obj[key] = value;
}

Then just call it with `assignProp(derp, "datKey", "datVal");`

Comment: single line is not a shorthand :0 because I still need `else` to generate error

Comment: That's why I said "not really"